# Convert a [System.Drawing.Bitmap] to [File.IFileAbstraction]

Tags: powershell, system.drawing, taglib-sharp

#### Task

In PowerShell, I want to add a picture as ID3V2 tag with the help of [taglip-sharp](http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/2.1.0.0/) library.
Usually you do it this way:

```
# Load taglib-sharb library
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( (Resolve-Path "..\Common\taglib-sharp.dll"))

# Load MP3 file
$media = [TagLib.File]::Create("C:\MusicFile.mp3")

# Load picture
$pic = [taglib.picture]::createfrompath("C:\MyAlbumArt.jpg")

# Add picture to MP3
$media.Tag.Pictures = $pic

# Save Mp3 
$media.Save()
```

#### General problem

The above works only if your picture is a file located somewhere locally.
But I have a picture as `[System.Drawing.Bitmap]` object which has no filepath to load it with `createfrompath`.

Before you say *Then just write it to disc*: I'd rather avoid saving them since my final script processes many pictures and mp3 files. And I don't want to write  and delete hundreds of pictures.

#### Specific question

I see that taglib also has another method called [`CreateFromFile(File.IFileAbstraction )`](http://taglib-sharp.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.0.3.3plus-pdfsg-3/classTagLib_1_1Picture_186ceec951fc54e66ae6942539dc3c9b.html#186ceec951fc54e66ae6942539dc3c9b) to load a picture. But how do I convert a `[System.Drawing.Bitmap]` into a `IFileAbstraction`?

The closest help I found on the net was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176757/how-to-convert-ipicture-to-image-net-4-5-taglib-sharp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239918/taglib-sharp-how-to-use-the-ifileabstraction-to-allow-reading-metadata-from-str). But it's for .NET 4.5 and I am by no means able to convert this into PowerShell syntax

[Here is the documentation of taglib-sharp's picture object](http://taglib-sharp.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.0.3.3plus-pdfsg-3/classTagLib_1_1Picture.html) if it helps.

Comment: Coul you add a link to the `taglib-sharp.dll` file that you are using?

Comment: @CB. Done. Thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy version is to just call the [c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176757/how-to-convert-ipicture-to-image-net-4-5-taglib-sharp) in powershell (as described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx))

```
  $refs = @(
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Drawing.dll",
"d:\taglib-sharp.dll"
)

$Source = @"

 namespace YourNamespace
    {
        public class Helper
        {
            public static TagLib.IPicture[] GetPictureFromBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap img)
            {
                return

                    new TagLib.IPicture[]
                    {
                        new TagLib.Picture(
                            new TagLib.ByteVector(
                                (byte[]) new System.Drawing.ImageConverter().ConvertTo(img, typeof (byte[]))))
                    };

            }
        }
    }
"@ 

Add-Type -Path $refs
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $refs -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp  

# Load MP3 file
$media = [TagLib.File]::Create("C:\MusicFile.mp3")

# Load picture into System.Drawing.Image
[Bitmap]$pic =[System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("C:\MyAlbumArt.jpg")

# Add picture to MP3
$media.Tag.Pictures = [YourNamespace.Helper]::GetPictureFromBitmap($pic)

# Save Mp3 
$media.Save()
```

The full powershell version:

```
function GetPictureFromBitmap([System.Drawing.Bitmap]$bitmap)
{
    $converter = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.ImageConverter
    $byte_vec = New-Object -TypeName TagLib.ByteVector -ArgumentList $converter.ConvertTo($bitmap, [byte[]])
    $picture = New-Object -TypeName TagLib.Picture -ArgumentList $byte_vec
    $picture_list = New-Object TagLib.IPicture[] 1
    $picture_list[0] = $picture
    return $picture_list
}


$refs = @(
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Drawing.dll",
"d:\taglib-sharp.dll"
)

Add-Type -Path $refs

# Load MP3 file
$media = [TagLib.File]::Create("C:\MusicFile.mp3")

# Load picture into System.Drawing.Image
[Bitmap]$pic = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("C:\MyAlbumArt.jpg")

# Add picture to MP3
$media.Tag.Pictures = GetPictureFromBitmap($pic)

# Save Mp3 
$media.Save()
```

Tested in powershell v3

Comment: One caveat: My Powershell 4.0 complained about `[Bitmap]` so I had to remove it